Name of a movie about scientist creating a human clone
I need to find a movie about a human clone I have seen before (a color film around 1995-1997 and I think it's an American film).
The main character is a scientist(?), he tries to make a clone using his DNA but when it's near successful, something happens and the scientist can't destroy the process, so the clone is created with a crazy personality.
The two of them are like linked together, when the clone gets hurt anywhere, the scientist gets hurt the same like the clone. The clone then feels lonely and demands the scientist create a woman for him; so the scientist creates one using his wife's DNA but ultimately fails, and it make the clone so angry that it fights with the scientist. They fight near an abyss(?) and then all fall into it.
That's all I can remember, hope someone can help me find it!

We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Clearly the description of the film you're looking for is basically a slightly modified retelling of Frankenstein, substituting resurrection for cloning, providing advancements on nature vs nurture and quantum entanglement. I would think that there can't be that many of them, but you may want to try searching from that angle. I would, but I have to get off the computer for a bit.

It does sound like you're looking for a version of Frankenstein, this particular one being TV movie Frankenstein from 1992 with Randy Quaid as the Monster.

Dr. Victor Frankenstein creates his creature, who escapes into the countryside to find that humanity has only pain and sorrow for him. But a psychic link between created and creator draws the two ever nearer, until their paths must inevitably cross again...

The creature is pretty much his clone, they feel pain when the other one is hurt, and Frankenstein does try to create a bride for him from his fiancee's DNA which then fails, angering the Monster. You can see their psychic link in this clip:



